# How to show slide console on laptop and slide-show in the projector using Libreoffice 4.2 on Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, libreoffice

I'm trying to setup my laptop (Dell D420) with Lubuntu 14.04 and Libreoffice 4.2 to show a slide presentation to a VGA projector. I used ARandR to make a screen layout where the laptop screen (resolution 1280x800) shows the left side of the desktop and the VGA projector (1024x768) the right side.

I tried a number of configurations and settings to no success except one that work partially: Going to Slide Show menu and Slide Show Settings I set Multiple Displays to All displays. In doing so I see the slide show on the projector but only the edition mode in the laptop screen. Trying the other settings for Multiple Displays will give:

Display 1: Console shows on the laptop screen but the slide show doesn't appear in the projector screen (instead it appears in the background of the laptop screen)

Display 2 (external display): Shows the console fully on the laptop screen but doesn't show the slide show in the projector.

Auto External (Display 2): Same as Display 2.

If I set ARandR to mirror the display only the console will be mirrored and not the slide show. Somebody could tell me a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. I wonder if it's related to the graphic card (mine is ATI Radeon). As a temporary solution I exported my presentations to PDF and use the "PDF presenter console" which works similarly to the "libreoffice presenter console". Installed via Synaptic. Then, select your pdf > right clic > open with "pdf presenter console".

Comment: Hi thanks. I don't think it is the graphics card since I work using multiple monitors with this laptop without issues. I will try the solution using the PDF presenter console.

Answer (score 1):

Download the portable version of Libreoffice 3.3 from [this list](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portable/files/) an use Impress for your presentations. This version can coexist with the installed one (the buggy 4.2.x or 4.3.x or whatever). I tested it and it works. By the way, it seems that this problem affects only Lubuntu. I tested a few live-distros: Ubuntu-Unity, Mint Mate and PCLinuxOS LXDE and the presenter-Console works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description was fix to my problems. I have 14.04, had **exactly** the same problem **until** I projected VGA to the right side of laptop. I did it from command line with xrandr (eDP1 is my laptop screen and VGA is external): `xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output VGA --auto --right-of eDP1`. However, I tried ARandR (which is a GUI for xrandr) and it worked this way as well.

I have different hardware, though.